# Pinescript timeframe since last crossover

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5

I'm quite new to pinescript v5 and can't figure out how to get the timeframe between MA crossovers.

For example, an ma crossover indicates a downtrend,  I need the timeframe(candles) since last crossover indicating an uptrend.

Sounds like there should be a simple solution, yet I can't find one.

[image: timeframe between MA crossovers]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ta.barssince()` function or a simple counter for that.

> **ta.barssince:** Counts the number of bars since the last time the
> condition was true.

```
bars_since_ma_crossover = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(ma1, ma2))
```